# Service stack global exception handling

Tags: servicestack

I have an application built with ServiceStack and ServiceStack.Razor.  I'm having trouble getting error handling configured the way I want.  Here is the goal:

- HttpError w/StatusCode = 401 or 403 should redirect to a "Access Denied" page.
- HttpError w/StatusCode = 404 should redirect to a "Not found" page.
- Everything else should redirect to a generic error page.  We don't want any ServiceStack-style error messages to be displayed.

First I tried using CustomHttpHandlers for the 401, 403 and 404 errors.  That worked until I set the GlobalHtmlErrorHttpHandler to capture other errors.  What I found was the GlobalHtmlErrorHttpHandler was always hit first and all errors were redirected to the global error page.

Then I removed the GlobalHtmlErrorHttpHandler and used AppHost.ServiceExceptionHandler, and that works fine as long as the offending exception is thrown from inside a service.  If an error occurs outside a service we still get the ServiceStack error message.  Also I had to add an "escape clause" so that 401, 403 and 404 errors are passed through to the appropriate CustomHttpHandler.

So then I set the AppHost.ExceptionHandler to capture everything else.  Here's a snippet from my AppHost.  I feel like I must be missing some way to handle this that's much simpler.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

```
    public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
    {
        SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig
        {
            DebugMode = false,
            AllowFileExtensions = { "swf", "webm", "mp4" },
            CustomHttpHandlers =
            {
                { HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, new RazorHandler("/AccessDenied") },
                { HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, new RazorHandler("/AccessDenied") },
                { HttpStatusCode.NotFound, new RazorHandler("/NotFound") }
            }
        });

        // For exceptions occurring within service methods:
        this.ServiceExceptionHandler = (req, exc) =>
        {
            // Allow the error to fall through to the appropriate custom http handler;
            // This feels like a kluge.
            if (exc is HttpError)
            {
                IServiceStackHttpHandler handler = null;
                if (this.Config.CustomHttpHandlers.TryGetValue(((HttpError)exc).StatusCode, out handler))
                {
                    return new HttpResult() { View = ((RazorHandler)handler).PathInfo.Substring(1) };
                }
            }

            Log.ErrorException(String.Format("Error handling {0}: {1}", req.GetType().FullName, JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(req)), exc);
            return new HttpResult() { View = "Error" };
        };

        // For exceptions outside of service methods:
        this.ExceptionHandler = (req, res, op, exc) =>
        {
            Log.ErrorException(String.Format("Error handling request {0} {1}", op, req.AbsoluteUri), exc);
            res.Redirect("~/Error".ToAbsoluteUrl());
        };
```

Comment: I find your solution simple, concise and explicit. The only thing I would do is to define the handlers in a class as static methods and test them individually. Why dou you need another solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom exception handling in ServiceStack REST service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604265/custom-exception-handling-in-servicestack-rest-service)